# how to change password for admin in plone 4.3

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone 4.3 in Windows 2008 with IIS.

Not like visions before Plone 4.3, like Plone 4.1.5, I can change password for "admin" in ZMI manage Pages: `/acl_users/users.`

In Plone 4.3 I cannot find page /acl_users/users.

Tried to reset password by reset password link instead, got exceptions.

Comment: AFAIK it Zope acl_suers should be still there, otherwise Plone cannot function. If you need emergency user see http://developer.plone.org/hosting/zope.html#adding-users-from-command-line-reset-admin-password

Comment: Do you mean "In versions before Plone 4.3", you can change the password in the ZMI?  Your question isn't making sense, otherwise.

You can't change the password through the Plone reset method, because admin is a Zope user, not a Plone one.

Answer (score 0):

The Zope User Manager has always been /acl_users/source_users, iirc (it is in my Plone 4.1 versions).

Just try /acl_users/manage_main...

Comment: Problem solved.
The reason I did not see /acl_users/users page is that I have virtual_hosting mappings at the root of ZMI that direct all requests for domain.com and www.domain.com to the root my Plone site.

Thanks for helping.